# Display datetime with php

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I have a column with the datatype datetime in sql server and i would like to echo the date only with php.

Currently I'm using this function to output everything:

```
<?php
include 'DB_Connect.php';
$query = ("select * from information");
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

echo $row['time'];
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: What is the output of this?

Comment: Can you tell what time value is stored in database.

Comment: 2013-06-12 12:20:15.047

Comment: ummm... Where does the `$row` variable come from? Turn on notices (error reporting), because the code you pasted is throwing errors. Unless that's not your actual code, in which case please post that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['time'])); // in Y-m-d format
```

**Edit**

You can also use this code

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-06-12 12:20:15.047');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

## Output

```
2013-06-12
```

## Codepad

Comment: I'm getting this date: 01-01-1970

Comment: Check the value of date in your database

Comment: That should work, do a var_dump of $row['time'] and put the answer here.

Comment: object(DateTime)#1 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-06-13 09:48:19" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Asia/Kuwait" }

Comment: @Allan You have to use `$row['date']`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar It is a datetime formate (2013-06-12 12:20:15.047) and i want to show the date.

Comment: @Allan Are you fetching the results? use `sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);` to fetch the results.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I copied the code and it works perfect if you type the date manually in. I got to check my select statement or database then..

Comment: @Allan check your code and put the actual date coming from DB in the provided code. :)

Answer (score 2):

No problem is that you haven't fetch the value from your sqlsrv_query result. That is why not getting any value.

use sqlsrv_fetch_array after that query.

```
 <?php
 include 'DB_Connect.php';
 $query = "select * from information";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);
 $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
echo $row['time'];
 echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['time']));
?>
```

It should work.

Comment: echo $row['time']; gives nothing back and echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['time'])); gives 1970-01-01 back

Comment: Try now. I haven't notice the bracket you are using in $query. That should not be there.

Comment: Answer me whether it works or not.

Comment: Stil giving me 1970-01-01.. what does that date means?

Comment: It means it is nor fetching any value. Any blank value when it use in strtotime() function it gives 1970-01-01. Please check the table for its value or print_r($row) after $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt); .

Answer (score 1):

In the realm of string based solutions, this is pretty straightforward.

A Y10k safe solution:

```
$date = strtok($row['time'], ' ');
```

A Y10k unsafe solution:

```
$date = substr($row['time'], 0, 10);
```